# Questions about about_scope.rb in Ruby Koans

Tags: ruby, scope

I'm doing Ruby Koans exercises now and am encountering some difficulties in understanding how the scope works in the below codes:

```
class AboutScope < Neo::Koan
  module Jims
    class Dog
      def identify
        :jims_dog
      end
    end
  end

class String
end

  def test_nested_string_is_not_the_same_as_the_system_string
    assert_equal false, ::String == "HI".class
  end

  def test_you_can_get_a_list_of_constants_for_any_class_or_module
    assert_equal [:Dog], Jims.constants
  end
end
```

I have 2 questions about the above codes:

1. Why `::String`'s class is String?
2. Why Jims.contants is `[:Dog]` rather than `["Dog"]`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would it be `["Dog"]`?

Comment: Your code is not properly closed.

Comment: Thanks! I closed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The relevant code is in the namespace of `AboutScope`. By default, `String` will refer to `AboutScope::String`. In order to refer to the `String` in the root environment (or the one within `Object`), `::` is attached. With it, `::String` refers to the root `String`.
2. `Module#constants` by design, returns an array of its constants' names expressed as a symbol. It could possibly be designed to return an array of strings, but for expressing closed class static things, symbol is better fit than string. Especially before recent Ruby, strings were newly created every time a new string literal was read, whereas a symbol is created only once for different occurrences of the same symbol. For things that are likely to be called multiple times within a code it was more efficient to have them as symbols rather than as strings.

Comment: +1. Further to #2, the symbol `:Dog` already exists because constant names are automatically interned (see `Symbol.all_symbols`), so it's much simpler to return the Symbol that already exists than to initialize a new string `"Dog"`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Now i'm more much clear now.